# alfresco constraint-handlers per field

Tags: alfresco-share

I have created a custom alfresco share form and would like to attach some fields with constraint-handler. I have handlers that are working BUT i have realised that thy only work on one field only. My question is, does it mean I cannot have several constraint handler in the same form? I need to validate number field, calculated date diffence  fields and do some other calculation in the same form. Is this possible in alfresco share? And How do I achive this is its possible?

Also which is the best event to add in a date field with constraint handler? is it onchage, onblur or on select in alfresco share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible. Take a look here: https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Forms#constraint-handlers_2

Some had issues with it on Alfresco on 4.0.x versions.

And if your on that version, then you can for sure do the constrain handling in your model.

Comment: I have followed the link. Created a js file with two functions. but I can only validate one field. which calls the first function in the js. The first function uses webscript and is working fine but the second one should calculate difference of two selected dates and show the result in a  custom field. Can this be achived? and if yes, kindly tell me how.

Comment: Just create a seperate js file per validation. I'm not sure if you can use one js.

Comment: thanks @Tahir Malik. I managed to create all my functions in one js file and reference them. Validation per field is now working perfectly. I am able to validate 6 fields in the same form using one js file. thanks alot.

Comment: Hi Tahir, I've tried this per field constraint, but my validation-handler is called for any change in the form and not only for the specified field. Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a complete control over the custom form using an alternative way, you can implement the form field validation handler using javascript directly. I mean, you can add a listener to control when the form is submitted, and add a condition (it doesn't matter if it's quite complex) to cancel the submission. So, you could use a code like this:

```
//Add a listener to control when the form is submitted
document.body.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {

     //If there are wrong values
     if(wrongValues()){
          //Cancel the event
          event.stopPropagation();
          event.preventDefault();
     }
}, true);
```

If you want more details about this solution, you can visit this [post](http://howtobrothers.com/2017/08/02/how-to-implement-form-field-validation-handlers-in-another-way/)

Comment: The question was to use several constraint handlers in a form with multiple fields where constraint handlers are in line with the elements and not the whole form. The answer works on the whole form after submitting but not the answer as expected.

Comment: Form submission is just only one example, you can follow the same approach to manage any kind of event and enforce any constraint to any field in your form, in any way you need, just using Javascript.